# error in selenium driver = webdriver.firefox()

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I ran the following code

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

But an exception was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\zoaoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Users\zoaoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\zoaoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\zoaoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\zoaoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, could you describe what you've tried already? Have you checked that Firefox is installed on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a compatible version of [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) somewhere in your PATH.

Comment: install `strace` and run `strace geckodriver` at the command line. you should see it wait at `futex(0x7f5907c6e9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 27127, NULL`. if not, something is wrong.

Comment: easier yet, just run `geckodriver --help`